# How to increase the number value of a field in sobject

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to increase the value of **number** field  in an SObjects, how could I do this ?

Comment: To answer the last question, you cannot alter fields purely with SOQL.  You must first fetch the record and then update it as you are doing now.

Comment: @mast0r I rolled this back as to a new comer it got confusing with the answer below, and I think that answer is valid. Be interesting to see if some others come up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it using this way

```
object = [SELECT Id, views FROM SObject WHERE ID =: id ];
object.view++;
update object;
```

Comment: You better update your existing question rather than create a new answer that is actually not an answer.

Comment: I was going to update the question, but I thought that this would be another question. People may want to ask about the same thing in the question :)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @mast0r I will create a new question about the SOQL only

Comment: @KeithC sorry, I thought it would be better to create a new question

Comment: I think this is a valid aswer. Why would you update a question with it's solution ? In my experience this has always been the recommended and preferred way of doing things on stackexchange sites.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I guess mast0r edited it. And thx I'll keep using this way.